# Django get_initial class based view method not working

Tags: python, django, django-class-based-views

I'm trying to use `get_initial` within a `FormView` to pre-populate the field "Subject" to have a "Wholesaler is interested" text, but it's not working.  If it matters, I'm using Django 1.5, Python 2.7. Here is my code.  Am I missing a step?

```
class ContactView(FormView):
    """
    ContactForm is a ModelForm
    """
    template_name = 'core/contact-us.html'
    form_class = ContactForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('products:index')
    initial = {'subject': 'I am interested in making a wholesale purchase'}


    def get_initial(self):
        """
        Returns the initial data to use for forms on this view.
        """
        return self.initial

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = {'initial': self.get_initial()}
        return kwargs

    def form_valid(self, form):
        cd = form.cleaned_data
        contact = Contact.objects.create(**form.cleaned_data)
        if contact:
            print 'contact created'
        else:
            print 'not created'
        if contact is not None:
            # send contact email
            msg = contact_email(name=cd['name'], email=cd['email'], subject=cd['subject'], message=cd['message'])
            msg.send()
            # Add success message 
            msg = 'Your contact email has been successfully sent.  We look forward to speaking with you.'
            messages.info(self.request, msg)
        return super(ContactView, self).form_valid(form)
```

**EDIT**

I removed the `get_initial` and `get_form_kwargs` but still no luck.  Here is a paste of my `Form` if that helps.  Do I need to attach the `initial` for what I would like to put in the `Form` in some way? Thanks for your help!

```
class ContactForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Contact  
        fields = ('name', 'email', 'subject', 'message',)
        widgets = {
            'message': forms.Textarea(attrs={'cols': 20, 'rows': 20}),
        }
```

Comment: 'it's not working' is not very helpful error message, can you elaborate?

Comment: You shouldn't need to define either `get_initial` or `get_form_kwargs` here, try removing then both and see if it helps.

Comment: I added an edit with more detail.  @DanielRoseman, I tried removing those two methods, but it still didn't work.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using `FormView`, try `CreateView`. It's a subclass of `FormView` which takes care of your actual model.

Also, how do you display the form in the template? If you manually go through all the fields you might be not displaying the initial value.

Comment: This is the correct answer.  I just didn't know enough about Django and hadn't used `CreateView` at the time of posting the question, so didn't know.  I could have saved a lot of spaghetti code using `CreateView`!!